# Program counter not advancing

Tags: assembly, embedded, arm

I am trying to debug a function `Reset_Handler()` written in assembler (which I do not understand, but was provided as part of a standard library). Using GDB, I go through every single instruction using `ni`. Here is what I get:

```
(gdb) ni
0x08005dc4 in Reset_Handler ()
(gdb) ni
0x08005dc6 in Reset_Handler ()
(gdb) ni
0x08005dc6 in Reset_Handler ()
(gdb) ni
0x08005dc6 in Reset_Handler ()
(gdb) ni
0x08005dc6 in Reset_Handler ()
```

In effect, the program pointer gets "stuck" on `0x08005dc6`. Is this normal behaviour, or should the program pointer be advancing each time I do `ni`? Below is the start of `Reset_Handler()`:

```
    .section  .text.Reset_Handler
  .weak  Reset_Handler
  .type  Reset_Handler, %function
Reset_Handler:  

/* Copy the data segment initializers from flash to SRAM */  
  movs  r1, #0
  b  LoopCopyDataInit

CopyDataInit:
  ldr  r3, =_sidata
  ldr  r3, [r3, r1]
  str  r3, [r0, r1]
  adds  r1, r1, #4

LoopCopyDataInit:
  ldr  r0, =_sdata
  ldr  r3, =_edata
  adds  r2, r0, r1
  cmp  r2, r3
  bcc  CopyDataInit
  ldr  r2, =_sbss
  b  LoopFillZerobss
/* Zero fill the bss segment. */  
FillZerobss:
  movs  r3, #0
  str  r3, [r2], #4
```

**EDIT**: Here is the disassembled instructions:

```
disas
Dump of assembler code for function Reset_Handler:
   0x08005dc0 <+0>:     movs    r1, #0
   0x08005dc2 <+2>:     b.n     0x8005dcc <LoopCopyDataInit>
   0x08005dc4 <+4>:     ldr     r3, [pc, #40]   ; (0x8005df0 <LoopFillZerobss+16>)
=> 0x08005dc6 <+6>:     ldr     r3, [r3, r1]
   0x08005dc8 <+8>:     str     r3, [r0, r1]
   0x08005dca <+10>:    adds    r1, #4
   0x08005dcc <+0>:     ldr     r0, [pc, #36]   ; (0x8005df4 <LoopFillZerobss+20>)
   0x08005dce <+2>:     ldr     r3, [pc, #40]   ; (0x8005df8 <LoopFillZerobss+24>)
   0x08005dd0 <+4>:     adds    r2, r0, r1
   0x08005dd2 <+6>:     cmp     r2, r3
   0x08005dd4 <+8>:     bcc.n   0x8005dc4 <Reset_Handler+4>
   0x08005dd6 <+10>:    ldr     r2, [pc, #36]   ; (0x8005dfc <LoopFillZerobss+28>)
   0x08005dd8 <+12>:    b.n     0x8005de0 <LoopFillZerobss>
   0x08005dda <+0>:     movs    r3, #0
   0x08005ddc <+2>:     str.w   r3, [r2], #4
   0x08005de0 <+0>:     ldr     r3, [pc, #28]   ; (0x8005e00 <LoopFillZerobss+32>)
   0x08005de2 <+2>:     cmp     r2, r3
   0x08005de4 <+4>:     bcc.n   0x8005dda <FillZerobss>
   0x08005de6 <+6>:     bl      0x8005c64 <SystemInit>
   0x08005dea <+10>:    bl      0x8000184 <main>
   0x08005dee <+14>:    bx      lr
End of assembler dump.
```

Comment: Stack pointer or program counter?  What is at 0x08005dc6? Smells like RAM.  If your automatic display is stack pointer, change it to program counter and disassemble instruction.  If control has transferred to a typical default abort handler, the SP will not chage because such handlers are usually simple 'jump to myself' loops.

Comment: @MartinJames: Sorry, it's program counter.

Comment: Hmmm. Loading r3 doesn't seem very exciting :(  Are you sure that what you are looking at is, in fact, what you think it is?  I've been led astray myself so many times with incorrect versions of source files, map files etc etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the code and disassembly you've posted, I'd guess that the address that's in `_sidata` is invalid.  `_sidata` is loaded into `r3`, so when

```
 ldr     r3, [r3, r1]
```

is executed, an invalid access causes another processor reset, which then executes until it hits that instruction again.  Or something like that.

Check what's in `_sidata`.

---

Some additional notes:

I see that the instruction at address xxxx uses `r0` but I don't see where `r0` has been initialized in `reset_handler()`.  It's possible that the code that calls `reset_handler()` might have already set up `r0` properly, but to know for sure we'd have to see the exception vector table and the code that the reset vector actually points to. (I'm assuming this is for an ARM7 or similar - let me know if I've guessed incorrectly), where the exception vector table might look something like (borrowed from ethernut.de) which would vector to a label named `_start` on reset:

```
.global __vectors
__vectors:
ldr     pc, [pc, #24]   /* Reset */
ldr     pc, [pc, #24]   /* Undefined instruction */
ldr     pc, [pc, #24]   /* Software interrupt */
ldr     pc, [pc, #24]   /* Prefetch abort */
ldr     pc, [pc, #24]   /* Data abort */
ldr     pc, [pc, #24]   /* Reserved */

/*
* On IRQ the PC will be loaded from AIC_IVR, which
* provides the address previously set in AIC_SVR.
* The interrupt routine will be called in ARM_MODE_IRQ
* with IRQ disabled and FIQ unchanged.
*/
ldr     pc, [pc, #-0xF20]   /* Interrupt request, auto vectoring. */
ldr     pc, [pc, #-0xF20]   /* Fast interrupt request, auto vectoring. */

.word   _start
.word   __undef
.word   __swi
.word   __prefetch_abort
.word   __data_abort
```

Comment: I think you are right for `_sidata` being an invalid address. As for the initialisation of `r0`, I think it is done on the first line of `LoopCopyDataInit`. (Reset handler calls `LoopCopyDataInit` as the second instruction.)

Comment: If the load of r3 generates a data abort, should not the single-step identify it?

Comment: @MartinJames: you'd think so, but you'd also expect that executing a single-step on `ldr r3, [r3, r1]` would advance the program counter!  I don't know the exact toolchain in use or how the exception vectors are set up.  I do know that a long while ago when I was messing around with an OpenOCD JTAG driver and the old Zylin CDT plugin for GDB in Eclipse targeting an ARM7, things didn't always behave stably.

Comment: @Randomblue: yes - I completely missed the `b  LoopCopyDataInit`.

Comment: @MichaelBurr - you're probably right - a loop with PC not changing loks so much like an error handler that it probably is, no matter wh... OH!! has the mode and register set got swapped, maybe, and the debugger has not noticed that an interrupt has swapped out r8-r15?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it depends :-)

What it depends *upon* is the instruction at `0x08005dc6`. It's quite possible that in a reset handler, you may have an instruction such as:

```
0x08005dc6 jmp 0x08005dc6
```

which would exhibit that behaviour.

You should check to see what's actually *at* that location, with something like:

```
disas 0x08005dc6 0x08005dcf
```

Comment: It's indeed program counter, thanks. How can I check the instruction at that specific location? Should I use `objdump`?

Comment: @Randomblue, `objdump`, no, not unless you're a masochist :-) Since you're already _in_ `gdb` (using the `ni` command), just use the `disas` command as per my update.